Rolling mean over an unstacked, multi-index
I have a CSV file like the following:
Animal,Day,Action,Seconds
dog,1,eat,10
dog,1,play,20
dog,1,drink,30
cat,1,eat,18
cat,1,play,28
cat,1,drink,21
rabbit,1,eat,34
rabbit,1,play,19
rabbit,1,drink,29
dog,2,eat,20
dog,2,play,20
dog,2,drink,10
cat,2,eat,28
cat,2,play,38
cat,2,drink,31
rabbit,2,eat,24
rabbit,2,play,34
rabbit,2,drink,30
dog,3,eat,30
dog,3,play,20
dog,3,drink,26
cat,3,eat,11
cat,3,play,22
cat,3,drink,32
rabbit,3,eat,50
rabbit,3,play,20
rabbit,3,drink,10

Representing how much has each animal spent doing each action each day (e.g. the dog spent 10s eating on day 1).
Using Pandas, how can I show a rolling average of Seconds over 3 days, per Animal, per Action? I want the output to look something like this:
                 Seconds             rolling_drink        rolling_eat        rolling play
Action       drink eat play            
Animal  Day                             
dog     1        30  10   20          30                    10                    .
        2        10  20   34          20                    15                    .
        3        26  30   34          22                    20                    .
cat     1        21  18   28          21*                   .                     .
        2        31  28   38          26                    .                     .
        3        32  11   22          28                    .                     .
rabbit  1        29  37   19          .                     .                     .
        2        30  27   34          .                     .                     .
        3        10  50   20          .                     .                     .

Notes:
. = real value, but no point in calculating each
* = to draw your attention to the rolling mean "resetting"
The main point being that rolling resets when the animal changes, i.e. the numbers from different animals aren't rolled together.
Here's what I tried:
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
x = df.set_index(['Animal', 'Day', 'Action']).unstack('Action')

x['rolling_eat'] = x[('Seconds', 'eat')].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean()
print(x)

This almost gave me what I wanted, but rolling doesn't restart when the animal changes. I'd assume if I indexed over Animal and Day, I'd get a rolling mean per Animal per Day. But nope. And I fail to understand what I'm doing wrong.

A groupby will separate your dataframe into multiple subframes that you can individually aggregate on:
pivoted = df.pivot_table(
    index=["Animal", "Day"],
    columns="Action",
    values="Seconds",
    aggfunc="sum",
)
result = pd.concat(
    [
        pivoted,
        pivoted.groupby("Animal")
        # Use an expanding window since we want to include all the previous
        # days
        .expanding()
        .mean()
        .droplevel(0)
        .add_prefix("rolling_"),
    ],
    axis=1,
)


This does indeed solve the issue as presented, and I accepted the answer. Thanks a bunch!
But... if my Day column is an actual date, and my rolling window is defined by a time delta (e.g. 5 days), I get into trouble, because time delta apparently isn't supported on a multi-index. Is there anything that can be done then? I can't just set window=5 as the entries for some days might be missing (day 1 can be followed by day 5), so I really do need a window of minimum 5 days.
